# Why does my WebGL varying not pass the values from my vertex shader to the fragment shader?

Tags: canvas, glsl, webgl

My goal is to slap a texture on a Cube.
I'm using webGL 1 on Chrome.
My UV coordinates varying doesn't appear to be working properly.
It appears as if the values aren't passed to the fragment shader.

Vertex Shader code:

```
attribute vec3 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_vertexUV;

uniform mat4 u_mvp;

varying vec2 v_uv;

void main() {
    v_uv = a_vertexUV;
    gl_Position = u_mvp * vec4(a_position, 1);
}
```

Fragment Shader code:

```
precision mediump float; 

varying vec2 v_uv;

uniform sampler2D u_texSampler;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texSampler, v_uv).bgra;
}
```

Running my program produces the following:

[image: canvas printscreen]

I see my cube, it sources color from the texture, but only uses the color of the first texel for the whole shape. Which suggests my UV vector is empty.

I can confirm this by trying to use the data from my uv vector as a color:

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(v_uv,0,1);
```

Which gives me the following:

[image: canvas printscreen #2]

A black cube. No values in my UV vector...

The weird thing is that if I use the uv vector in the vertex shader like so:

```
gl_Position = u_mvp * vec4(v_uv, 0, 1);
```

Suddenly I get values in my uv vector in the fragment shader, which using as color values produces this:

[image: canvas printscreen #3]

Or as Uv coordinates in my texture like so:

```
gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texSampler, v_uv).bgra;
```

Produces the following:

[image: canvas printscreen #4]

Which correctly sources color from my texture...

Why does my varying not pass the values to the fragment shader unless it is used in gl_Position?

Comment: You need to post the code setting up the buffers and attributes for your positions and texcoords

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake.

I'm storing my gl object locations in different arrays such:

```
webGlBuffers = [];
webGlShaders = [];
webGlPrograms = [];
webGlAttribLocations = [];
webGlUniformLocations = [];
webGlTextures = [];
```

In my gl.EnableVertexAttribArray calls I was referencing the wrong array. ie:
I was calling

```
gl.EnableVertexAttribArray(webGlShaders[0]);
```

When I should be calling

```
gl.EnableVertexAttribArray(webGlAttribLocations[0]);
```